# Concatenating props and static values in style={{}} in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a component I am passing a height as props so it can be used at page level like so (minified code)

```
<Component style={{height}} />

Component.propTypes = {
   height: PropTypes.string, //make sure it's a string
}

Component.defaultProps = {
   height: "100%", //100% otherwise defined
}
```

This can be used later as

```
<Component height="100%"/>
<Component height="50%"/>
<Component height="20%"/>
...
```

And renders as

```
<div class="component-blah-blah" styles="height: 100%;"></div>
```

I want to add `overflow-x: hidden` to the party but as a default and non-changeable prop. So that regardless of how they use the styles prop, it will always carry out the overflow-x I defaulted. Like so:

```
<Component height="100%"/>
<div class="component-blah-blah" styles="height: 100%; overflow-x:hidden"></div>

<Component height="50%"/>
<div class="component-blah-blah" styles="height: 50%; overflow-x:hidden"></div>

<Component height="20%"/>
<div class="component-blah-blah" styles="height: 20%; overflow-x:hidden"></div>
```

I know I can concatenate classes in string and props like this using the --> ` <-- and the $ sign, but not with a double bracket as style requires.

I'm looking for the syntax for something like this

```
className='${classes.myPropClass} myCSSclass'
```

which renders as `class="myPropClass myCSSclass"` , but for inline styles, not classes...and I can't assing overflow to a class. For other complicated reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `style` prop takes an object. The inner brackets `{}` are just the syntax for creating an object inline. So just add the desired property to that object in the render function:

```
const Component = ({height}) => (
    <div class="component-blah-blah" styles={{height, overflowX: 'hidden'}}></div>
);
```

Comment: I need to do the cahnge at component level. I can't recode thousands of existing tables (it's used on a table by the way)

Comment: @LOTUSMS Why do you think you need to recode them? Just do that one level higher then. You should add that to your `Component` render logic of course. And that just once. Every rendering of that component will automatically be affected by that change.

Comment: The inline style needs to be at a specific level. Either higher or below and the css overflow acts differently. I need to make this change at the component level so it propagates to all the pages where that component is being used

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Please do not post just unrelated snippets. You can apply my answer on any level you like. I can't see a problem with that. Just do it in the `render()` function of the component that should apply the default.

Comment: Oh wait! I misunderstood you. You meant adding it to the Component where I am declaring the prop, not the Component use in the pages! ...lol. soryy man. Long day and it is only 12PM

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. :)

Comment: I didn't post unrelated snippets. I think I've been here long enough to knwo how this works buddy. Anyhow, thanks. It worked

Comment: @LOTUSMS I didn't mean to say that. It was just hard to see what renders what in your example that probably why we missunderstood. If I had more information of the component structure I could have provided a better example. Nevermind. If it solved your problem please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The example code you've given doesn't seem to match the description you wrote along with it.  You said (emphasis, mine):

> So that regardless **of how they use the styles prop**, it will always carry out the overflow-x I defaulted.

But the code you've put here doesn't show there being a `style` prop.  It just shows there being a `height` prop.  If the user of this component is only given a `height` prop to use, there's no way that value could ever overwrite your `overflowX` style property.

**But**...  if you're trying to allow the consumer to pass in *their own style object in the props*, and then ensure that they can't overwrite your desire to implement an `overflowX` feature, you should use a spread operator to effectively concatenate the user's style, with your style, while keeping your style from being overwritten.  It would look something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const styleFromProps = { display: 'none' };
    return (
      <p
        style={{
          ...styleFromProps,
          display: 'inherit',
        }}
      >
        Is this displayed???
      </p>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is a live example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-spread-operators-in-styles

Notice in this example that the `styleFromProps` object has a `display` value of `none`.  But the contents of the `<p>` tag still display.  Because the hardcoded value for `display` is listed in the style object *after the display value that's passed in*.  In CSS, if an attribute is declared twice, the last one "wins".

So if you're allowing the user to pass in a style object as a prop, but you want to ensure that they don't overwrite some of the "critical" styles that you're using, you can do it in this way.